# Changing font size by using UISlider

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I can't get this to work, and this code is not inside viewDidLoad()

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!

@IBAction func slider(sender: UISlider) {
    let senderValue = CGFloat(sender.value)
    label?.font = UIFont(name: (label?.font.fontName)!, size:senderValue * 20)
    label?.sizeToFit()

}
```

If you could help in any way that would be great.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What is the problem? Have you verified that your `slider:` func is being called? Are you sure that the label's font is set initially?

Comment: if you get the value of slider what is the problem

Comment: I'm trying to get my label to increase and decrease in size and it just won't happen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code does not have to be inside viewDidLoad.

Do you use autoLayout to position your view?

This should work:

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!

@IBAction func sliderAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("Slider value \(slider.value)")

    self.label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(CGFloat(slider.value * 20.0))
}
```

Check if:

- UIFont object is initialised correctly.
- Remove `label?.sizeToFit`. Normally, the label text is drawn with the font you specify in the font property.
- Constraints are correctly set on the UILabel object.

Comment: I've added missing constraints to UISlider and UILabel, I removed label?.sizeToFit like you said to. Yes I use autoLayout to position my view, not sure what you mean by initializing the UIFont correctly. Just updated my question with an image.

Comment: Can you share your code (swift file + xib + fontFile) so we could take a look? I have tested the solution above and it works as it should be.